# Who killed Lancer?

Tags: carnival-phantasm

Towards the beginning (after the OP) of the *Carnival Phantasm Special Season* OVA, the two waitresses of the Ahnenerbe Cafe, Hibiki and Chikagi, come into the cafe to find that someone has killed their co-worker, Lancer!

Based on the evidence at the scene of the crime, who amongst the extended cast killed Lancer? What was their motive (if any)?

[image: Whodunnit?!]

Comment: Including the "Based on the evidence at the scene of the crime" part could make this very subjective and open to discussion.

Comment: @atlantiza I wouldn't be so sure... the series makes a lot of subtle references that's easily missed on a first watch. E.g., Sakura cameos in the background in the [Date all the Heroines](http://i.imgur.com/969EPrd.jpg) scenario.

Comment: Spoiler! It's just a running gag referencing Kenny from Southpark. I doubt that they even thought about a reason, they just let him die.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lancer always dying is a joke in carnival phantasm, the reason why he dies is or who kills him is of little importance. For example, in one of the first episodes of carnival phantasm when the cat characters are talking with the TV on we hear about a man in blue thighs being killed in a car accident. It is of course Lancer, and he just died for no reason whatsoever.

For your case though not a lot of people could have killed him because we can see black keys in his body, the weapon of the church. It means a priest must have killed him.

The only person I could see doing that would be Kotomine, because we also see him asking Grail-kun to do something because Lancer is completely useless, and Grail-kun gives him the "Servant Strengthening Tool" (The kitchen knife in the picture).

Comment: The black keys make sense... but what's up with the the kitchen knife?

Comment: It looks a lot like the "Friend-maker" from Grail-kun, so maybe Kotomine tried to become friends with Lancer but it didn't go as planned.

Comment: It would seem to be the "[Servant Strengthening Tool](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZlVHXT3edG4)!" I believe we have our motive now. If you include that in your answer, I'll accept it.